# How Google counts the number of anchor texts and keywords in a Blogspot home page?

Tags: keywords, anchor, blogspot

Since Google consider the anchor text and keyword counts of a webpage for search ranking, I have one doubt regarding this; how Google counts the number of anchor texts and keywords in a Blogspot home page? In the case of website’s home page, it’s possible to count the anchor text and keywords from its index page but in the case of Blogspot, home page would contains all the published posts (not for all blogs and it based on the theme of the blog).

In my blog, I have posted so many posts which contains many anchor links, when I searched the keyword density of my Blogspot (`www.example.blogspot.com`) its showing more count for some keywords. Does it is a spam and how Google handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Keyword Density is so oldschool*

Google uses many methods to establish what a page is about, the fact that your using a keyword density check indicates that your following, or read somewhere a guide on SEO that is many years old. Keyword density used to be a huge factor but nowadays since this was abused its hardly a factor and the only concern you should have is if your over doing it the keywords.

***Do not get caught up in oldschool SEO - Write for your audience, not the search engines.***

Blogspot uses canonical links so if you have many articles displaying on the front page then Google will be able to establish which text belongs to which page, keywords that are found on the menu bar, blog roll, and footer are irrelevant as these are not within the fold of content. Look up below the fold, Google has for some time now being able to detect where the content is on the page and what px across the content is.

There's nothing special about Blogspot and all blogs are treated similar.

Comment: "Do not get caught up in oldschool SEO - Write for your audience, not the search engines."   This and for so many reasons